# Best way to create a string containing multiple copies of another string

Tags: c++, string

I want to create a function that will take a string and an integer as parameters and return a string that contains the string parameter repeated the given number of times.

For example:

```
std::string MakeDuplicate( const std::string& str, int x )
{
    ...
}
```

Calling `MakeDuplicate( "abc", 3 );` would return `"abcabcabc"`.

I know I can do this just by looping x number of times but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: Why 123?  Don't you mean MakeDuplicate("abc",3)?

Comment: What makes you be so sure that there must be a better way?

Comment: Just since you were wondering about a standard way, no, there isn't one. There *is* a constructor that will repeat a single character `n` times. `std::string s(9, 'A');`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't see a problem with looping, just make sure you do a reserve first:

```
std::string MakeDuplicate( const std::string& str, int x )
{
    std::string newstr;
    newstr.reserve(str.length()*x); // prevents multiple reallocations

    // loop...

    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: Looping is fine, its just one of those things that 'feels' like there would be a more explicit way of achieving it, but maybe there isn't.

Comment: I don't think there's an an idiomatic way of doing what you ask in c++.

Comment: A slightly more efficient version would probably be to begin with copying the actual string, and then looping `x-1` times. Although it would require a check for `0` to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Matthieu M.- I had thought about that, but you'd still probably be doing two memory allocations: one when you construct the string, and another to make it the max size.  One upfront allocation for the whole thing is probably faster.

Answer (score 7):

At some point it will have to be a loop.  You may be able to hide the looping in some fancy language idiom, but ultimately you're going to have to loop.

Answer (score 4):

For small 'x' simple loop is your friend. For large 'x and relatively short 'str' we can think of a "smarter" solution by reusing already concatenated string.

```
std::string MakeDuplicate( const std::string& str, unsigned int x ) {

  std::string newstr;
  if (x>0) {
    unsigned int y = 2;
    newstr.reserve(str.length()*x);  
    newstr.append(str);
    while (y<x) {
      newstr.append(newstr);
      y*=2;
    }
    newstr.append(newstr.c_str(), (x-y/2)*str.length());
  }
  return newstr;
}
```

Or something like that :o) (I think it can be written in a nicer way but idea is there).

EDIT: I was intersted myself and did some tests comparing three solutions on my notebook with visual studio (reuse version, simple loop with preallocation, simple copy&loop-1 without preallocation). Results as expected: for small x(<10) preallocation version is generally fastest, no preallocation was tiny bit slower, for larger x speedup of 'reuse' version is really significant (log n vs n complexity). Nice, I just can't think of any real problem that could use it :o)

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative to a loop, its called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), and of recursion [tail-recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) is the nicest variety since you can theoretically do it till the end of time -- just like a loop :D

p.s., tail-recursion is often syntactic sugar for a loop -- however in the case of procedural languages (C++), the compiler is generally at loss, so the tail-recursion is not optimised and you might run out of memory (but if you wrote a recursion that runs out of memory than you have bigger problems) :D

**more downvotes please !!**

recursion is obviously not a construct used in computer science for the same job as looping

Comment: It's elegant, but when somebody types in MakeDuplicate("very long string ... ", 200000) they are gonna cry :)

Comment: Looping can be parallelized, but recursion cannot.

Comment: @lp well yes -- I agree (compiler optimization), but if you wrap the recursion in question with another recursion you can paralelise .... and such code in my experience is far more robust -- think Erlang :D

Comment: C++ does not (generally) optimize tail recursion. You could end up with a stack overflow with such a solution.

Comment: You could delete your answer instead of asking for more downvotes. Downvotes cost 1 point.

Comment: Why should I ? an answer is never complete unless it explores all relevant avenues. I have not even disagreed with the potential pitfalls of recursion...

Comment: Why is it downvoted? It's ideal answer to demonstrate why elegant recursive solution is not suitable (for large x at least).